# Docker Desktop - unable to install (Windows 11)

Tags: docker, installation, wsl-2, docker-desktop, windows-11

I have been running Docker for the past 1 year on my work laptop. I recently started receiving requests to update the version. Ever since then, my Docker Desktop installer has been failing. Please keep in mind that I have already tried the following and it hasn't worked:

- Ensured that Docker desktop has been completely uninstalled on my work device
- Tried installing the previous docker desktop versions that were working
- Unchecked the box to install the required modules for wsl (tried it with and without)

Here is the error I receive:

**Component CommunityInstaller.ExecAction failed: Process InstallerCli.exe exited with code 1
at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.d__24.MoveNext()**

Any suggestions on why this is happening and how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Deleted the folders:

C:\ProgramData\Docker (if you cant, rename the folder)
C:\Program Files\Docker
After this, docker 4.6.0 was installed successfully.